# Meteor.js sidebar delay

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I customised the accounts-ui, and the following code is in my site. After logged in, every time I refresh or route to another page. It always show 'Sign In' first, after a short delay(depends on internet speed), it will finally display the user's full name.

Is there any way to keep it displaying user's full name constantly instead of having the short delay?

Many thanks.

```
{{#if currentUser}}
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{currentUser.profile.firstname}} {{currentUser.profile.surname}}</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="{{pathFor 'myAccountListing'}}">My Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="logout">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      {{else}}
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="{{pathFor 'loginPage'}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign In</a></li>
      </ul>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Something is forcing Meteor to re-render this piece of the DOM. My guess is that it has something to do with your `currentUser` helper.

Comment: I guess it might be possible to render `currentUser` first, then load the page. But don't know how to achieve that.